# Create a properties frame in Java

Tags: java, swing, properties, jtable

I am trying to make a properties frame just like the one in netBeans (or Visual Studio). My problem is that I don't know exactly how to design it. First I thought I'll make it with JTable (2 columns, multiple rows) but then I realised that on the second column I will have different types of values (booleans, String, color choosers, etc.), but I think that JTable allows only 1 type of data to be placed in a column.

I would like someone to tell me "JTable allows multiple data types on the same column" and show me how to do it, or tell me a different approach to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perfectly tell a JTable to have a column that contains `Object`, this way you will be able to put whatever ou want in.

BUT.

You'll then have to implement a very good `TableCellRenderer`/`TableCellEditor` pair in order to display whatever the cell contains.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a Grid or GridBag layout inside of a JScrollPane, then dynamically populate the cells of the grid with different editors depending on the data type of the property.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use external libraries, the [JGoodies `FormLayout`](http://www.jgoodies.com/downloads/libraries.html) is really suited to create such dialogs. Just take a look at the screenshots in [their demo](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/formsdemo/index.html).

There is also a rather good [PDF available](http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=formlayout%20documentation%20pdf&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jgoodies.com%2Farticles%2Fforms.pdf&ei=Db4FT66lJtGgOsGP5bkJ&usg=AFQjCNH6uYWbCRAyrzOkgAs5Blj8ToMv9Q) containing with some examples and explanations.